# @SpringBootTest for a non-spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot

I am creating a non-spring-boot application using spring-rest, spring-data-jpa etc and I would like to do integration testing using spring boot (1.4.1.RELEASE). Note that I don't have a SpringApplication class or @SpringApplication annotation anywhere

On my test class I have

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = MyConfiguration.class)
public class MyIT { }

@RestController
public class MyController { }
```

This is starting an embedded tomcat and I can see that my controller is being initialized, however, I get a 404 when calling my service using TestRestTemplate. It appears that DispatcherServlet does not seem to know about my controllers

Also, I had to define a servletContainer bean as follows

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.setPort(9000);
    factory.setSessionTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    return factory;
}
```

Am I missing any configuration for Spring to have my controllers visible to embedded tomcat? I tried using @EnableAutoConfiguration @ComponentScan on the test class but they don't have any effect. I have wasted two days on this and any hints are greatly appreciated!!

Complete MyIT class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = { TestContextConfiguration.class })
public class MyIT {

@Value("${local.server.port}")
private int serverPort;

@Resource
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Port:" + serverPort);
    System.out.println("Hello:" + this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/", String.class));
}
```

}

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello called");
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

Output of the test

```
Port:9000
Hello:<404 Not Found,<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.5.5 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.5</h3></body></html>,{Content-Type=[text/html;charset=utf-8], Content-Language=[en], Content-Length=[992], Date=[Wed, 05 Oct 2016 14:26:46 GMT]}>
```

Comment: Could you share MyIT content?

Comment: Added complete MyIT class

Comment: You are requesting **"/"**  with restTemplate, do you handle **@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)** in your rest controller **MyController**

Comment: yes I do. Used @Getmapping("/")

Comment: I have a separate JUnit for just the controller using MockMvc and that works fine

Comment: The error means that MyController is not scanned and loaded by spring. MyController is in main package and MyIT is in test package, right? May be you should add @ComponentScan("mycontroller.package") in MyIT to scan MyController

Comment: Thanks Issam. As I mentioned in my original post, I did try with `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.controller.package")` and it doesn't help. I enabled debug log and I can see that `o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory` is creating my controller bean (and my System.out on the controller constructor is being printed), so the controller is definitely being loaded; it is just not being wired correctly. Now that I am not using `@SpringApplication` (this not being one), I wonder what that annotation sets up that is not done by `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: I give it a try and it's working. see https://github.com/ielatif/stackoverflow/tree/master/SpringBootTest-for-a-non-spring-boot-application

Answer (score 22):

This can be achieved by creating a TestConfig inner class and annotate it with @SpringBootConfiguration like:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public static class TestConfig {
}
```

Then, in your test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(...)
@Import(MyIT.TestConfig.class)
public class MyIT {

    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @ComponentScan("com.example")
    public static class TestConfig {
    }
}
```

Note that TestConfig class also has @ComponentScan annotation. This is used by Spring to find your applicacion beans.

Comment: Although this solution works in way to hacky and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Have a test configuration that define beans that you want to use, annotate with  `@TestConfiguration`

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public Faker getFaker() {
        return new Faker();
    }
}
```

Then your test class would like this

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyService.class,TestConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyIT {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    Faker faker;
}
```