# Can't Autowire Service in JUnit 4 Test in Spring Boot Multi Module Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have following project structure:

```html
-module1
--src/main/java/at.flobau.demo.module1
---model
----Product.java
---service
----ProductService.java
---TestConfiguration.java

--src/test/java/at.flobau.demo.module1.service
---ProductServiceTest.java

-module2
--src/main/java/at.flobau.demo.main
---MainApplication.java
```

The Application class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"at.flobau.demo.main"})
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("at.flobau.demo.module1")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"at.flobau.demo.module1"})
public class PocApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PocApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The Service looks like this:

```
@Service
public class ProductService implements IProductService {

    @Autowired
    private IProductRepository productRepository;

    ...
}
```

The test Class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class }, loader = 
AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ProductServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    ...
}
```

The test configuration file looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("at.flobau.demo")
public class TestConfiguration{ }
```

IntelliJ tells me, that the ProductService inside the test cannot be autowired. When i do run the test i get an exepction:

```
Error creating bean with name 'ProductServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 
'productService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
'at.flobau.demo.module1.products.service.ProductService' available: expected at least 1 bean which 
qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: I got a sample application with junit test cases procedures using mockito

https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/products-api

Comment: Try explicitly add the package name of ProductService into @ComponentScan("at.flobau.demo") in your config class

Comment: Main class is in module2, so module1 independently is not a spring boot application, try adding @ SpringBootConfiguration to your test config. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858226/springboottest-for-a-non-spring-boot-application] refer this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using field injection (even though is possible) and use constructor injection. This will solve this problem as you will be able to pass the service from the constructor but it will also be useful in the future as you can locate usages and trace objects in your code way better than field injections which are "hidden"

So I recommend instead of trying to solve your problem here to refactor your class in constructor injection and pass the service from there either by directly creating the object in your test or by creating a configuration for your test that will generate the object and give the arguments it requires

something like

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { GeneralTester.TestConfig.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class GeneralTester {
  @TestConfiguration
  public static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public IProductService productService(final IProductRepository productRepository){
     return new ProductService(productRepository);
    }
    @Bean
    public IProductRepository productRepository(){
      return mock(IProductRepository.class);
    }
  }

  @Autowire
  public IProductService productService;

  @Autowire
  public IProductRepository productRepository;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    reset(productRepository);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(productRepository);
  }

  @Test
  public void doSmth() {
    //... your setup
    when(productRepository.save(any())).thenReturn("something");
    //... your call and assertions
    verify(productRepository).save(any());
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. However my ProductService doesn't have parameters, so i can't implement it like this.

Comment: Yes I saw that does not have parameters but my suggestion was to refactor it and use a constructor with parameters instead of the field injection that you have @Bioaim

Comment: Also I just realized you are doing a unit test and you have `@SpringBootTest`. This is not needed as it will only slow down your test by A LOT ( instead of half second it will take the time that your server requires to boot.. ) unit tests should not require the server to run. thus my test example does not have `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: ok understood that now. i do get this error now: `Invalid bean definition with name 'productService' defined in class path resource [at/flobau/demo/products/service/ProductServiceTest$TestConfig.class]: @Bean definition illegally overridden by existing bean definition`

Comment: I need to see your code cause this means you missed a small detail . Maybe try a pastebin ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/i0REGMbv something like this should do the trick

Comment: I want to unit test my service class though, not the repository

Comment: Exactly. thats why you mock the repository because you dont want to test it and you use the actual object of the service class. Mocking defines how the class will behave "if a findall is called then those 2 objects will return" this is defined for the repo. so pass the mock in the service and then you call the findAll. if the findAll service method calls the repo the action will be the defined ( as it leaves the service domain ) anything else inside the service domain are under inspection !

Comment: ok. i get it. but you are autowireing the `IProductService` - shouldn't that be the `ProductService` ?

Comment: You should autowire on interfaces. if for example next month you delete `ProductService` for the `CoolerProductService` your test will require a single word to change. the initialization on the configuration

Comment: i am unforunately still getting an applicationcontext error: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'at.flobau.demo.products.service.ProductServiceIntegrationTest' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: However, i got it to work like this: https://pastebin.com/WphtnMwc

But now, i want to do an Integration test, without mocking. And evertime i am trying that I get an error saying that there is no ApplicationContext found. The SpringBootApplication sits in another module.

Comment: Actually the second one just loads the application context. nothing else as you dont call your service that you are testing ( which is null ) . Import was my bad. Use `@ContextConfiguration` . As for the integration testing . It should not be done in the service layer. it should be on your API / Controller layer where your Main is located. integration tests require 0 mocks within your application but also require much more configuration to make the context load

Comment: Hm I don't think so. The Test Method uses `productService.findByName("Banane")`. When i insert `Bananee` instead, the returned Product is null. It works just fine. The problem with our controller is, that it is aswell in another module. I want to go with cucumber when doing integration tests. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: I am clueless about cucumber but I know that you can do the integration tests with JUnit just fine . even with other modules! You just have to write your integration test on the module with the main ( as the module with the main has the controllers) and load the configuration that main loads. As for the unit test I am honestly not convinced its working! give it a more detailed check just to be safe ( add a breakpoint in the actual method and see if it will stop there. )

Comment: I'll check it. The Controller is not in the same module as the main Application.For example i cannot run `@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplication.class` because it is aswell in another module on its own.

Comment: Ok then you are probably following an approach I am not familiar with. Nevertheless the integrations can be done. You can even create a dedicated module for the tests so you wont have them spread around. Have a look at how spring does the test module i mentioned here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream

Comment: Thank you for helping Michael! The project is already set up, i cannot change this anymore unfortunately. The project atm has 3 modules. [1] Main Module, where the `SpringApplication.class` sits. [2] Data Module where we have the Repositories and Services and [3] where we have the `Controllers`. Tests should be in the corresponding modules. Is there a way i can access `@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)` in the non-main Modules?

Comment: Never happened to require that so I cannot give you a clear answer :/ But because now we are getting off-topic if my answer did not help you an a comment was something that helped you please let me know to modify the answer so someone else will be helped also by reading it! also marking it as helpful would help future users :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest(classes = ProductService.class)`

Comment: I am getting this then: Caused by: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.esag.tyr.poc.products.service.IProductRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: Read it carefully. Its trying to create a bean of IProductRepository inside it. Try to Mock it with the annotation @MockBean.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a bean of the service in the test configuration class?

```
@TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan("at.flobau.demo")
public class TestConfiguration { 
    @Bean
    public ProductService productService() {
        return new ProductService();
    }
}
```

Comment: While testing when you create configuration you should use `@TestConfiguration` annotation. Just a suggestion